# PHP, CURL, WebDAV, and SEARCH method

Tags: php, search, curl, webdav

How would I recreate the following curl statement in PHP?

```
curl http://www.example.com/path/to/folder/ -X SEARCH -d @dasl.xml
```

Here is what I have so far, and the "dasl.xml" file is what is tripping me up.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/path/to/folder/");
$fp = fopen("webdav.xml", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "SEARCH");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

The dasl.xml file contains the XML to query WebDAV. Is there an option that I can use to pass that file along? Or is there a way to pass along the contents of the file as a string or something else?

The error statement that I'm currently getting is

> DaslStatement:267 - SAX parser error Premature end of file.

Thanks for the help.

**Update:**

Here is an example dasl.xml file:

```
 <d:searchrequest xmlns:d="DAV:">
  <d:basicsearch>
    <d:select>
      <d:prop><d:getcontentlength/></d:prop>
    </d:select>
    <d:from>
      <d:scope>
        <d:href>/container1/</d:href>
        <d:depth>infinity</d:depth>
      </d:scope>
    </d:from>
    <d:where>
      <d:gt> 
        <d:prop><d:getcontentlength/></d:prop>
        <d:literal>10000</d:literal>
      </d:gt>
    </d:where>
    <d:orderby>
      <d:order>
        <d:prop><d:getcontentlength/></d:prop>
        <d:ascending/>
      </d:order>
    </d:orderby>
  </d:basicsearch>
</d:searchrequest>
```

More info on DASL here: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc5323.html and [http://www.webdav.org/dasl/][2]

Comment: You need to explain what is it inside `dasl.xml`

Comment: Sure thing. The DASL file is XML used to build a search. Below is an example DASL file. This file does not match my data, so I that's why I'm not sending it to the WebDAV server.

Comment: <d:searchrequest xmlns:d="DAV:">
  <d:basicsearch>
    <d:select>
      <d:prop><d:getcontentlength/></d:prop>
    </d:select>
    <d:from>
      <d:scope>
        <d:href>/container1/</d:href>
        <d:depth>infinity</d:depth>
      </d:scope>
    </d:from>
    <d:where>
      <d:gt> 
        <d:prop><d:getcontentlength/></d:prop>
        <d:literal>10000</d:literal>
      </d:gt>
    </d:where>
    <d:orderby>
      <d:order>
        <d:prop><d:getcontentlength/></d:prop>
        <d:ascending/>
      </d:order>
    </d:orderby>
  </d:basicsearch>
</d:searchrequest>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents` with a custom context. So you would not need cURL for that. Something similar to this:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/path/to/folder/';
$body = file_get_contents('dasl.xml');
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
      'method' => 'SEARCH',
      'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'content' => $body,
    )
));

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```